# NSOperation waitUntilFinished waits a long time

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation

I am using an `NSOperation` subclass (called PointsOperation) to do some calculations in the background in my app. Due to user behaviour, these calculations might need to be canceled, and new calculations started. In that case, I will create a new `PointsOperation` instance, and add it to the same `NSOperationQueue` as the first one. As the first thing in the main method of the PointsOperation, it will check whether another operation is already running, and cancel it.

Because the operations are using some shared caches, they cannot be (and don't need to be) running in parallel. Therefore, the second operation will wait until the first one has finished. The resulting code for the main method looks something like this:

```
static NSOperation *currentOperation = nil;
- (void) main
{
   // setting up autorelease pool, catching exceptions, etc
   @synchronized(lock) {
      if (currentOperation != nil) {
         [currentOperation cancel];
         [currentOperation waitUntilFinished];
      }
      currentOperation = self;
   }
   while (!calculationsFinished && ![self isCancelled]) {
      // do calculations
   }
   currentOperation = nil;
   // releasing autorelease pool, etc
}
```

This all works fine, the first operation gets cancelled, and the second waits for it to finish, and then starts calculating.

The problem is: it takes 3-10 seconds between the first operation ending the main method, and the second one to come out of the `waitUntilFinished`.

Does anybody have seen this before and knows what to do about that?

I have also tried, instead of the `waitUntilFinished`, to make the second operation dependent on the first, with "addDependency:" (in the init method, rather than the main). That also works, but has the same problem: the start of the second operation is a number of seconds behind the finish of the first method.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of its name, the `cancel` method does not magically cancel the operation.

> Canceling an operation does not immediately force it to stop what it
>   is doing. Although respecting the value returned by the isCancelled is
>   expected of all operations, your code must explicitly check the value
>   returned by this method and abort as needed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

If you did not write your code to check `isCancelled` property, so the operation's thread will run to the end no matter you cancel it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you can see in the code and description above, I do check isCancelled. Also, I have verified with NSLog statements that the operation does finish as a result of the cancel, and that the delay is definitely between the end of the main method of the first operation and the second operation coming out of waitUntilFinished.

Comment: @fishinear I'm sorry I missed it :(

Comment: Doesn't mean to nag you, but I notice you misspelled the variable in the line `[currentOparation waitUntilFinished]` and still got it compiled?

Comment: Well spotted! The code is a shortened version of the real code, I guess I made a typo when editing. Fixed it now

Comment: Well I hoped that you had declared the different variable somewhere else :(.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue here but my code just work fine with no such delay. This is my code:

```
@interface PointsOperation : NSOperation {
@private
    bool calculationsFinished;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int tag;

@end


@implementation PointsOperation 

@synthesize tag;

static NSOperation *currentOperation = nil;
static NSString* lock = @"LOCK";

- (void) main
{
    NSLog(@"Before autoreleasepool with tag: %d", tag);
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Before lock");
        // setting up autorelease pool, catching exceptions, etc
        @synchronized(lock) {
            if (currentOperation != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Before cancel");
                [currentOperation cancel];
                NSLog(@"Before waitUntilFinished");
                NSDate* beforeWait = [NSDate date];
                [currentOperation waitUntilFinished];
                NSLog(@"After waitUntilFinished took %f seconds", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:beforeWait]);                
            }
            currentOperation = self;
        }
        NSLog(@"Before while loop");
        int i = 0;
        while (!calculationsFinished && ![self isCancelled]) {
            // do calculations
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
            NSLog(@"Inside while loop = %d", i);
            calculationsFinished = (++i > 10);
        }
        NSLog(@"After while loop: i = %d", i);
        currentOperation = nil;
        // releasing autorelease pool, etc
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", @"End of method");
}

@end
```

And here's how I use it:

```
NSOperationQueue* q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
q.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [q addOperation:[PointsOperation new]];
}
```

The result of time took by `waitUntilFinished` came in two categories:

```
After waitUntilFinished took 1.002624 seconds
```

and

```
After waitUntilFinished took 0.000749 seconds
```

which depends on the timing of the call I think.

Maybe you should provide more of your code if possible, as problem might be somewhere else in your code.